# List renders data based on user

Tags: visualforce

I have creates a VF page based on this documented example:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetvar="cases">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:form id="theForm">
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                <apex:outputLabel value="View:"/>
                <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="list"/>
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!listviewoptions}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:panelGrid>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:dataList var="c" value="{!cases}" id="list">
                {!c.subject}
                </apex:dataList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This works well but I need to be able to filter the list views based on the user that is logged in.  Is this possible?  We have dozens of views and I do not want to have to create a custom view for each user to just show their records for each view.

Comment: what is each logged in user supposed to see? their own cases?

Comment: Set the List View's options to "My Cases" and it'll be filtered dynamically per user.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies.  The above code was used as an example.  We have over a dozen Account views used to distinguish different Account type.  yes I could reference the "MyAccount" view but this would show all of the users accounts and they would still have to filter through a list that will be much longer since it is not filtered like the other Views.

Comment: I added                                                                                           
<apex:variable var="" value="" rendered="{!LOWER(acc.owner.name) == LOWER($User.username)}">                                                                     
which limited the records to just the person that is logged in buth there are bullet points in place of the Account records that do not belong to the user that is logged in.